# Display modal when get parameter is set, Php bootstrap

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to display modal when user click on link and set parameter, but nothing happens and I don't know why this code doesn't work. Somebody to help ? Thanks

```
<div class="container-fluid" style="margin: 0 auto; width: 50%">
            <div class='btn-group'>
            <button type='button' class='btn btn-default dropdown-toggle' data-toggle='dropdown' aria-haspopup='true' aria-expanded='false' style='background-color: #4076BC; color: #fff;'>
                Action<span class='caret'></span>
            </button>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="#">Edit</a></li>
                <li><a href="test.php?deleteUser" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">Delete</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        </div>

<?php
            if (isset($_REQUEST["deleteUser"])) {
                echo '<div id="exampleModal" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
                          <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                            <div class="modal-content">
                              <div class="modal-header">
                                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                                <h4 class="modal-title">Modal title</h4>
                              </div>
                              <div class="modal-body">
                                <p>One fine body&hellip;</p>
                              </div>
                              <div class="modal-footer">
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
                              </div>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                        </div>';
            }
        ?>
```

Comment: so what should happen?open the link or open the model

Comment: If you want to open the modal: 
It's not enough to add the modal code in the page.
It needs to be triggered.
This code should open the modal `$('#myModal').modal('show')` (taken directly from the bootstrap page).

Comment: when click on link modal should open, this link: <a href="test.php?deleteUser" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">Delete</a>

Answer (score 0):

if you put modal code inside php if condition then it will not be inserted in the DOM. Place the modal code as it is. It will not display. Use Jquery to detect click or you can insert display block class in modal to show it and also use jquery to set form values to delete

Comment: I have solve problem now, put modal code into html and trigger modal after click, but don't have idea how to send user id . When i use test.php?deleteUser&id=UserId i send on this way. My href now is "#myModal" . Can i write for example "myModal&id=UserId" and handle that after if user click ok ?

Comment: Sorry for late response you can use Jquery to change/append ids. and better use jquery ajax to do this work